# AWS Lambda: automating access key rotation - how to enable in a VPC?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cdk, vpc

For my personal project, I want to create an AWS Lambda Function that rotates my access keys once every three months. I challenged myself to deploy the function in an isolated subnet in my default VPC, and use a VPC endpoint to perform SDK requests to the IAM service.

To create the VPC endpoint, I specify the IAM Identity Center as the service and build the VPC endpoint as following:

```
    vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint("some-id", InterfaceVpcEndpointOptions.builder()
            .service(InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.IAM_IDENTITY_CENTER)
            .securityGroups(List.of(iamVpcEndpointSg))
            .subnets(SubnetSelection.builder()
                    .subnets(List.of(isolatedSubnet))
                    .build())
            .privateDnsEnabled(true)
            .build());
```

When I test my lambda, a simple test request (`ListUsersResult users = iamClient.listUsers();`) times out after 60 seconds. Strangly, other VPC endpoints that I have created in the exact same way do work.

I have enabled VPC flow logs for debugging purposes, but I cannot trace back any traffic related to SDKs request in there (while requests to other services, via other VPC endpoints, are logged).

My questions:

1. **Is IAM_IDENTITY_CENTER the right service?** There is not much choice when it comes to IAM services, but the SDK corresponding to this service (`AmazonIdentityManagement`) does offer the desired methods.
2. **What are my options for further debugging?** VPC flow logs are not a success, but perhaps I can dig deeper into the issue with other tools / services.
3. Are there networking-related steps that I could make to inspect the connection?
4. Any other flaws that I overlooked?

Comment: IAM Identity Center **is not** IAM. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/what-is.html And afaik IAM does not offer VPC endpoints.

Comment: @luk2302 I see, I think I confused myself by the IAM Management Center SDK that offers the methods that I need. Thanks!